# Hide virtual key board in android and use my own

Tags: android

I have my own virtual key board application..I want to use it whenever there is an edittext field appears in the window..for eg, when i log in to gmail i want to enter my username and password through my virtual keyboard app..Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: virtual keyboard application?? Is it a kind of input method ? If yes, I think you can install your IME app into device and switch current IME to yours.

Comment: yeah, tats what i want..Can you tel how to switch current IME to mine..I am a newbie in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About switch current IME to yours:
You have to install your IME app first.
If no, that is maybe another problem.
Settings --> Language and Keyboard --> your IME should be there
and turn on the check box.

Comment: ok..I will tell my scenario..I am developing a security related application..So when that application starts it should disable the inbuilt virtual keyboard and use only my own virtual keyboard..All these have to be done programmatic-ally..Is it possible..If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple in Android.
Check this out..

```
  EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.setInputType(0);
```

Thats it. The Android's Virtual keypad will not pop up for this EditText.

Comment: This is for a particular edit text field..I want to use my own virtual keyboard even in webpages..